Wordpress Site Health - The REST API encountered an error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host
I have a Wordpress site version 6.6.2 running in production. When checking the Site Health, there are some critical issues I don't know how to solve.
One of the errors told that it couldn't resolve the host. However, my host is working normally when I go to link.

How can I solve this?
